# Почему не работает динамика в IE

Tags: javascript, html, php

При нажатии на ссылку загружается слой с формой авторизации.
В Chrome работает отлично
В Opera и Mozilla тоже открывается,
а IE говорит что у меня ошибка скрипта строка 5 символ 2, или так же при выполнении функции *close_autorization()* ошибка в строке 2 символ 2.

***indeх.php***

```
<html>
    <a href="javascript:autorization()">Вход</a>
    <p id="par" name="par"></p>
    <SCRIPT src="js/InputPlaceholder.js" LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> </SCRIPT>
</html>
```

***InputPlaceholder.js***

```
function close_autorization(){
    par.innerHTML='';
}
function autorization(){
    par.innerHTML='<b>Форма авторизации</b>';
}
```

Comment: Скиньте куда-то весь InputPlaceholder.js

Comment: Попробуйте переписать код через document.getElementById('...') .

Comment: Вот он весь: http://rv.tsu.tula.ru/InputPlaceholder.js

Comment: Та-же самая фигня.
IE начал показывать блок только когда я в форме удалил слои <div></div>
первоночально у меня было
par.innerHTML='<div>Форма авторизации</div>';
когда удалил, заработало. Но мне без <div>ов никак нельзя..

Comment: Просто ие-инвалидный браузер.Под него все и изгаляемся.Я уже отказ поставил ему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

href="javascript:autorization()"  - это моветон. Используйте событие onclick():

```
<a href="#" onclick="autorization(); return false;">Вход</a>
```

**Добавлено.**

Можно совсем убрать href, но тогда тег 'a' не будет восприниматься как ссылка и нужно будет прописывать стили явно. Как-то так:

```
<a style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; color: #3060A8;" onclick="autorization(); return false;">Вход</a>
```

И еще могут быть глюки в IE6

Comment: Илья, спасибо, работает. Спрашивается как теперь книжкам доверять.
А есть ли такой вариант, при котором в адресной строке не будет всплывать '#'

Comment: Можете убрать href="#". Но в таком случае укажите style="cursor: pointer", чтобы курсор принял обычный вид при наведении на ссылку.

Comment: Можно совсем убрать href, но тогда тег <a> не будет восприниматься как ссылка и нужно будет прописывать стили явно. Как-то так:

    <a style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; color: #3060A8;" onclick="autorization(); return false;">Вход</a>

Правда могут быть глюки в IE6

Comment: Дык вот return false как раз для того, чтобы не было решётки в адресной строке (т. е. браузер не выполнял переход по ссылке). Вероятно, внутри функции autorization возникает какая-то ошибка и до return false дело просто не доходит.

Answer (score 1):

Резюмируя все вышесказанное:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return autorization();">Вход</a>

Скрипт:
function autorization(){
    var blok='дофига кода';
    document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = blok;
    return false;
}
```

А вообще, лучше сразу напишите форму входа с `style="display:none"` и потом просто меняйте ей `style.display`.

Comment: Поподробнее можно? про форму входа.. Можно как нибудь 'дофига кода' заменить на форму сохраненную в файле autorizatiоn.php

Comment: Легко. В autorization.рhp пишете: `<form id="authform">...</form>`, в style.css: `#authform{display:none}`, в index.php: `<?include('autorization.рhp');?>` в том месте, где подключается форма и в InputPlaceholder.js в function autorization(): `document.getElementById('authform').style.display = 'block';` . Результат: в нужное место из отдельного файла подключается невидимая форма. При клике по ссылке она становится видимой. Все остальное - дело разметки.